# es2015 module syntax, how do I import a file that is outside of my project's directory

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am working on several projects at the moment and started extracting common functionality. I want to place this functionality in another file all of the other projects can reference as I work on it. The problem is I don't know how to gain access to that file using es2015 syntax.  I use babel, gulp, and browserify but this is more of a babel issue. The error that occurs is:

```
Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory
```

the import is like such:

```
import { jsFunction } from '../../../jsFile';
```

the file structure is as follows

```
jsfile
 |---- project1
 |---- project2
```

This is one directory above my project, and each project has there own gulp file.  How can I have several development projects import from yet another development project?

for reference my gulp task is

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    browserify(entryFile)
        .transform(
            babelify, 
            {presets: ["es2015", "stage-0"]}
         )
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
        })
        .pipe( source( outputFile ))
        .pipe( gulp.dest( jsBuidDir ))
        .pipe( connect.reload() );
   });
```

Comment: You may want to consider putting this common functionality in its own NPM package and including it as a dependency for each project that uses it. That way you can just import it from the `node_modules` directory relative to the project like your other packages.

Comment: Thank you.  I had not thought about the npm, but about a git project.  If I were to make this a npm project, is there tools to manage all of the updating files or would I need to write some type of script myself to handle that?

Comment: Check out https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

Comment: Did you install `es2015` preset? run `npm install --save babel-preset-es2015`

Comment: @RickRunyon that worked is there any cli tools that will handle to publish and updating of multiple projects?

Comment: Are you asking how you would cause those changes to propagate throughout all your other projects? That's kind of up to you, the easiest way would be to enforce some versioning scheme for the package and then running `npm install` inside the dependent projects in order to grab the changes each time the version is bumped.

Comment: @RickRunyon yes that is what I meant.  Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the loop on the comment tree above, my suggestion to OP was to publish his common code as an NPM package and include it in the projects that use it. Then, he could update this package incrementally and provide version updates in order to roll out new functionality throughout his projects.